# Sorting and Ordering in R

Tags: r, function, sorting, vector

I am currently working through an intro class and I and was having some difficulty with this particular problem:

1. Create a function that takes in a vector of numbers V.Size and a single number N as inputs and outputs a list object of size N where each list member is a vector that contains elements of V.Size such that the largest value in V.Size is in the vector of the first list item, the second largest value in V.Sizeis in the vector of the second list item, etc.  The (N+1) ordered value of V.Size should be in the first vector of the list, the (N+2) ordered value ofV.Size should be in the second vector of the list and so on.

Now, this is what I have done thus far, I am trying to make an example code:

```
V.Size <- c(5,4,2,3,1)
n <- 5
Function <- c(V.Size, n)
Function
[1] 5 4 2 3 1 5

sort(Function, decreasing=TRUE)
[1] 5 5 4 3 2 1
```

The issue I am having is with (N+1), (N+2) and its ordering.

Answer (score 0):

The first step to addressing this would be to create a vector of the list position for each element in sorted `V.size`. This is basically the vector (1, 2, ..., N, 1, 2, ..., N, ...), of total length `V.size`. You can get that with:

```
V.Size <- c(5,4,2,3,1)
n <- 2
rep(1:n, length.out=length(V.Size))
# [1] 1 2 1 2 1
```

Now you can use the `split` function to create a list based on these assignments:

```
split(sort(V.Size, decreasing=TRUE), rep(1:n, length.out=length(V.Size)))
# $`1`
# [1] 5 3 1
# 
# $`2`
# [1] 4 2
```